# Is this expression always irrational?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Is it right that

**$$\sqrt[a]{2^{2^n}+1}$$**

for every $$a>1,n \in \mathbb N $$

is always irrational?

Comment: No, it is not always irrational.

Comment: why isnt it, do you find a counterexample?

Comment: Yes, $a=1$.....

Comment: see now;D what about now?

Comment: Is $a$ necessarily an integer?

Comment: yes a>1 a natural number

Comment: You might add the tag `diophantine-xxx` to inform any reader that ***all*** your unknowns are assumed to be integer...

Answer (score 5):

As lhf notes, we just have to see that $2^{2^n}+1$ can never be a perfect power. However, since $2^{2^n}$ is a perfect power, using [Mihailescu's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture) the only pair of perfect powers differing by $1$ is $8$ and $9$, but $2^{2^n}$ can't be equal to $8$ for $n$ natural. So your expression is, indeed, always irrational.

(I guess I should note that using full Mihailescu's theorem here might be an overkill - 2 being a prime should let us give a relatively simple argument... but hey, whatever works :) )

Comment: i found a much faster proof xD was wondering if someone proved it already:D But thx, now i know more!:D Now i can focus on square-freeness... xD

Comment: If you have your own proof, you can post it as an answer here too.

Comment: hey dude whats ur opinion on the proof :)

Answer (score 2):

$\sqrt[a]{m}$ is rational iff it is an integer iff $m$ is an $a$-th power.

The question deals with [Fermat numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number).

Apart from the easy counterexamples, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number#Primality_of_Fermat_numbers) says that even a weaker version of the question is an open problem:

> Does a Fermat number exist that is not square-free?

Comment: proving this is always irrational, does not prove fermat numbers are square free.. :(

Comment: It might be possible to prove that Fermat numbers are never a perfect power without showing they are squarefree.

Answer (score 1):

$$a=1\to 2^{2^n}\in \Bbb Q$$
$$a=2\to \sqrt{2^{2^n}} \in \Bbb Q$$

Comment: i forgot the +1 sorry, and yeah i suggest a doesnt may be 1 ^^

Comment: It is not about $\sqrt{2^{2^n}}$, but $\sqrt{2^{2^n}+1}$.

Comment: $a=1$ still holds. $a=2^k, k\in \Bbb Z$ is now true $\forall n\ne 0$. Also note $\forall a$ there is an exception at $n=0$, which some argue is $\in \Bbb N$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I saw after editing.

Comment: See my earlier comment. Exceptions galore when $n=0$

Comment: lets keep n=0 out of mind, we are in natural numbers theres no 0, is it irrational always or not? What do you think?

Comment: @Zoetrope It is always irrational. The term under the root is even always squarefree, hence not an $a$-th power, so the conjecture.

Comment: is it only for even a irrational or also for odd? Square means even but also 3,5,7,11 power? Yeah but irrationality doesnt mean qure freeness, square freeness is stronger^^ How did you get your result that for every a>1,n it's irrational?

Comment: @Dietrich, I think Zoe has a point – it hasn't been proved, has it, that $2^{2^n}+1$ is always squarefree?

Comment: @GerryMyerson No, it is a conjecture, as I said.